# How to fix headers in angular?

Tags: angular, post, header, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to make a post request to add a book to a shelf in Google Books API but I'm getting back a 401 with the message `Login Required`, but the user is authenticated.

```
    addBookToShelf(shelfId: number, book: Book) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders()
            .set('content-type', 'text/plain')
            .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${getAccessToken()}`);
        const params = new HttpParams().set('volumeId', book.id).set('key', environment.API_KEY);

        const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves/${shelfId}/addVolume`;
        return this.http.post<ShelfBooksResponse>(url, {
            params,
            headers
        });
    }
```

```
    return gapi.auth2
        .getAuthInstance()
        .currentUser.get()
        .getAuthResponse().access_token;
};
```

What I do notice in the request is that the Authorization is not set but found in lazyUpdate. https://share.getcloudapp.com/6qu2AzkN

Comment: Hello! Did you check how interceptors work with http requests in angular? This might helps you: https://angular-academy.com/angular-jwt/

Comment: Looks like `getAccessToken()` is undefined when making the request, check the access token from the request header in the network tab.

Comment: access token isn't undefined...

Comment: Thx for the advice, I've learned new things. I found the solution. I needed to send the body as well even if it's an empty object